# threejs move multiple objects

Tags: typescript, three.js

I have a threejs scene with multiple objects. When I select one and move across the screen it works, if I select > 1 all objects are put on the same position as object 1. They do however need to stay where they are. Here is some code:

```
translateObjectTo(absX, absY, absZ) {
    this.selectedObjects.forEach((selection) => {
        if (absX !== null) {
            selection.translateX(absX - selection.position.x);
        }
        ...
    });
}
```

If I write selection.translateX(absX); it works but with a wrong value of course

Comment: Just trying to clarify: You have X objects scattered through your scene. You select all of them. You drag one 5 units in the +x direction, so you want all the others to translate 5 units in the +x direction from their current locations. Is that a proper summary?

Comment: Yes, it is multi object scene. I would like to select more than 1 and then move them along the axes relative to their original position (with one it works, with two it already doesnt), e.g. position of object 1 is (0,0,0), position of object 2 is (1,0,0), so moving them 5 units along the x axis should result in (5,0,0) and (6,0,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object3D.translateX` (and the other translate methods) is additive. This means if your X value is already 5, and you call `myMesh.translateX(5)`, your new `myMesh.position.x` will be `10`.

To this end, you want to calculate the difference between the dragged object's original `position.x` and its new `position.x`, then apply that different to all the other objects.

Here's some code/pseudo-code as a very loose example. If you want this to happen as you're dragging, you'll need to compute the difference for each frame (or however often you intend to update).

```
// start dragging
originalPosition.copy(dragObject.position)

// drag is done (or you're ready to update)
let xDiff = originalPosition.x - dragObject.position.x

// apply this difference to all selected objects (except the dragged one)
selectedObjects.forEach(function(obj){
  if(obj.id !== dragObject.id){
    obj.translateX(xDiff)
  }
})
```

Comment: thx a lot works like a charm but to be honest I don't understand why :) how is the first object different from the others? if I just loop over all selected objects and apply the distance (see my code snippet above) they get all assigned the position of object 1 and that was the root of my problem. can you enlighten me? :)

Comment: The problem with your original code is that you're subtracting each object's original location from the distance changed. This essentially reduces their new position to _only_ the translation.